# Override static pattern rule in Makefile (without it giving a warning)

Tags: makefile

I would like to use a static pattern rule to specify a default recipe for a class of targets, but override that recipe for a few specific targets.

Here's a trivial example that illustrates what I'm trying to do. For each directory that contains a file "test.py" I want to invoke the command "run_test.py", except when the directory is named "one" I want to invoke a different set of commands:

```
TESTS := $(shell find * -name "test.py" | xargs -I {} dirname {})

.PHONY: $(TESTS)

all: $(TESTS)

$(TESTS): %:
    python run_test.py $@

one:
    python run_test.py $@ mode=1
    python run_test.py $@ mode=2
    python check_results.py $@
```

This works, but gives a warning:

```
$ make
Makefile:12: warning: overriding commands for target `one'
Makefile:9: warning: ignoring old commands for target `one'
```

Is there another way to do this, or eliminate the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  A static pattern rule is really not a pattern rule: instead it's just a shorthand for writing a lot of explicit rules.

If you want to have most targets use one recipe but a few use another recipe, you should define a real pattern rule for "most" targets, not a static pattern rule, then use explicit rules to override:

```
%.o: %.cc
        g++ -c $< -o $@

test.o: test.cc
        g++ -Wall -c $< -o $@
```

Why do you want to use a static pattern rule instead of a regular pattern rule?

*ETA* You could also use target-specific variables:

```
CFLAGS =

test.o: CFLAGS = -Wall

$(OBJS): %.o: %.cc
        g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

*ETA2* OK, that's much different than your original example.

You have two obvious choices that I can see.  The first is to remove the special targets from the list; something like:

```
SPECIAL_TESTS := one

TESTS := $(patsubst %/test.py,%,$(shell find * -name "test.py"))

.PHONY: all $(TESTS)

all: $(TESTS)

$(filter-out $(SPECIAL_TESTS),$(TESTS)):
        python run_test.py $@

$(SPECIAL_TESTS):
        python run_test.py $@ mode=1
        python run_test.py $@ mode=2
        python check_results.py $@
```

The other way to do it is with target-specific variables that define the entire recipe, something like this:

```
TEST_RECIPE = python run_test.py $@

one: TEST_RECIPE = python run_test.py $@ mode=1 \
        && python run_test.py $@ mode=2 \
        && python check_results.py $@

TESTS := $(patsubst %/test.py,%,$(shell find * -name "test.py"))

.PHONY: all $(TESTS)

all: $(TESTS)

$(TESTS):
        $(TEST_RECIPE)
```

Comment: My targets aren't real files. I'm actually getting a list of directories that match a particular pattern and then invoking a command for each. For most of these directories its the same command, but for some I want to specialize the command.

Comment: Just because they aren't real files doesn't mean that you can't use pattern rules...?  If you gave an example that was closer to your actual use-case, it would be easier to give advice.  For example if the only difference between the recipes is something that can be contained in a variable, you could use target-specific variables to override the behavior of some of the targets.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the question with an example that more accurately captures what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Option 1 is the most attractive; I went with that. Now if only there were a way to build SPECIAL_TESTS automatically..

Comment: Well, since you're the only one who knows which directories need special handling I don't see how it could be generated automatically...?